# RowSelected - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to make so when I press a row on my UITableView, it will send some data to another UIViewController and make a seque.

However when testing it out, it gives me:

> System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object

The error seems to show here:

```
viewController.NavigationController.PushViewController (detail, true);
```

Here is my "RowSelected"

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Row: " + tableItems [indexPath.Row].Heading);

    //new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading, null, "OK", null).Show();
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);

    // Specially for Storyboard !!
    var detail = viewController.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("detail") as HolsteinItemViewController;
    detail.Title = tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading;
    detail.LoadUrl (tableItems[indexPath.Row].SubHeading);
    viewController.NavigationController.PushViewController (detail, true);
}
```

Exception caught:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Holstein.TableSource.RowSelected (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x0008e] in /Users/Emil/Projects/Holstein/Holstein/Code/TableSource.cs:41
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at Holstein.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/Emil/Projects/Holstein/Holstein/Main.cs:16
```

**TableSource.cs line 46**

```
viewController.NavigationController.PushViewController (detail, true);
```

**Main.cs line 16**

```
UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

Comment: Are both tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading and Subheading not null?

Comment: Both should be set, as they both show up in the cell

Comment: Is there some other property of detail that is expected but not defined?

Comment: If the null reference exception is thrown when you are trying to push the controller, it's most likely that the NavigationController property of "viewController" is null. Is that controller actually pushed on a navigation controller? Is it visible at the time, or just instantiated?

Comment: could you share the complete stack trace ?

Comment: Added the exception caught

Comment: Dimitris, its just instantiated.. Haven't really worked with tables before, but am always using storyboard.. Normally I just use PerformSegue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `viewController.NavigationController` property is null. According to iOS `UIViewController` reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationController)

> If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation
>   controller, this property contains the owning navigation controller.
>   This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a
>   navigation controller.

Apparently, that view controller is not part of a `UINavigationController` stack.

Comment: How do you add it to the stack?

Comment: By calling the UINavigationController's PushViewController method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324571/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-monotouch  please answer this