# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

NavigationController Takes null arguments when i want to navigate from one page to another page.
Here is my code:

```
var detail = Viewcontroller.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("FullgalleryimagesStoryBoardId") as fullgalleryimageinfo;
Viewcontroller.NavigationController.PushViewController (detail, true);
```

Viewcontroll and storyboard takes arguments correctly but NavigationController  throws an exception like above

What can i do?

[image]

```
try 
{
    UINavigationController  Navigationcontroller=new UINavigationController();
    var detail = Viewcontroller.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("FullgalleryimagesStoryBoardId") as fullgalleryimageinfo;
    //  Viewcontroller.NavigationController.PushViewController (detail, true);
    Navigationcontroller.PushViewController(detail,true);
} 
catch (Exception ex)    
{
    string exep=ex.Message;
}
```

i tried this code snippet there is no exception but there is no page navigation is done.

Comment: Please Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/19892199/3378413

Comment: Please post that exception.

Comment: I have added my exception please check it out.

Comment: Is your `detail` variable null?

Comment: no detail variable take arguments NavigationControll takes null.

Comment: Have you got a `NavigationController` in your storyboard? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/#Instantiate_Storyboards_Manually

Comment: yes i got a NavigationController in my storyboard

Comment: is navigation should perform from one view controll to another view controller.

Comment: Why don't you just use a segue to navigate instead of manually instantiating the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

If your `detail` variable is null, then either a controller with the ID  "FullgalleryimagesStoryBoardId" does not exist in the story board, or it exists, but it is not of type `fullgalleryimageinfo`.

Try the following and add a breakpoint after the line:

```
var detail = Viewcontroller.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("FullgalleryimagesStoryBoardId");
```

If `detail` is null, then the ID is wrong. If it is not null, then it is of a different type, in which case you have to set the type correctly.

Here is how to do it in Xcode:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qu62ncjehk7p8i/Screenshot%202017-02-09%2010.48.04.png?dl=0